# Proper compiler intrinsics for double-checked locking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, intrinsics

When implementing double-checked locking, what is the proper way to do the memory and/or compiler barriers when implementing double-checked locking for initialization?

Something like std::call_once isn't what I want; it's way too slow.  It's typically just implemented on top of pthread_mutex_lock and EnterCriticalSection respective to OS.

In my programs, I often run into initialization cases where the initialization is safe to repeat, as long as exactly one thread gets to set the final pointer.  If another thread beats it to setting the final pointer to the singleton object, it deletes what it created and makes use of the other thread's.  I also often use this in cases where it doesn't matter which thread "wins" because they all come up with the same result.

Here's an unsafe, overly-contrived example, using Visual C++ intrinsics:

```
MyClass *GetGlobalMyClass()
{
    static MyClass *const UNSET_POINTER = reinterpret_cast<MyClass *>(
        static_cast<intptr_t>(-1));

    static MyClass *volatile s_object = UNSET_POINTER;

    if (s_object == UNSET_POINTER)
    {
        MyClass *newObject = MyClass::Create();

        if (_InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(&s_object, newObject,
            UNSET_POINTER) != UNSET_POINTER)
        {
            // Another thread beat us.  If Create didn't return null, destroy.
            if (newObject)
            {
                newObject->Destroy();  // calls "delete this;", presumably
            }
        }
    }

    return s_object;
}
```

On a weakly-ordered memory architecture, my understanding is that it's possible that the new value of `s_object` is visible to other threads *before* other variables written inside `MyClass::Create` or `MyClass::MyClass` are visible.  Also, the compiler itself could arrange the code this way in the absence of a compiler barrier (in Visual C++, `_WriteBarrier`, but `_InterlockedCompareExchange` acts as a barrier).

Do I need like a store fence intrinsic function in there or something in order to ensure that `MyClass`'s variables are visible to all threads before `s_object` becomes somethings besides `-1`?

Comment: C++11: static global = initialize_global() is thread safe.

Comment: Also notice: The 'Double-checked locking' pattern is a broken pattern. See (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Comment: 1. See my reply to Dietmar about why function statics won't work.
2. Double-checked locking is broken due to weak memory semantics.  This is about using compiler intrinsics to do proper memory synchronization so that it doesn't break.  In other words, I'm well aware of it.

Comment: You may resort to std::call_once or boost::call_once

Comment: @Dieter no it's not. There are just some broken implementations of the pattern, but the pattern itself is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, the rules in C++ are very simple:

> **If there is a data race, the behaviour is undefined.**

In you code the data race is caused by the following read, which conflicts with the write operation in `__InterlockedCompareExchangePointer`.

```
if (s_object.m_void == UNSET_POINTER)
```

A thread-safe solution without blocking might look as follows. Note that on x86 a load operation with *sequential consistency* has basically no overhead compared to a regular load operation. If you care about other architectures, you can also use *acquire release* instead of *sequential consistency*.

```
static std::atomic<MyClass*> s_object{nullptr};

MyClass* o = s_object.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
if (o == nullptr) {
    o = new MyClass{...};
    MyClass* expected = nullptr;
    if (!s_object.compare_exchange_strong(expected, o, std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
        delete o;
        o = expected;
    }
}
return o;
```

Comment: The -1 thing was because a null pointer was a valid "initialized" state in my case, so I needed a way to distinguish between null and uninitialized.

I'm not really sure how your implementation differs from mine other than the lack of the nullptr/-1 distinction; I looked up what this std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_strong actually does in Visual C++ and it's just _InterlockedCompareExchange.

What about writes that occur inside MyClass::MyClass?  Can they get reordered to after the compare-exchange on weakly-ordered architectures, thus breaking?

Comment: @Myria: You are right. It wasn't clear from the code. `s_object` is the same as `s_object.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`. That makes the difference. The `nullptr` thing was only to simplify the example.

Comment: I apologize for that.  The union lameness was due to how I constructed the example - it was originally going to use a function pointer.  A union would've been necessary in order to compare-exchange the function pointer since _InterlockedCompareExchange takes void * not something like void (*)().  I've edited my original code to delete the union.  Your new compare_exchange_strong third parameter causes a memory fence?

Answer (score 0):

For a proper C++11 implementation any function-local `static` variable will be constructed in a thread-safe fashion by the first thread passing through this variable.

Comment: Microsoft still hasn't implemented this; Visual Studio 2013 doesn't support this feature of C++11, so it won't work on Windows (as my program also uses exception handling in the Windows build, which clang/GCC don't support).  They are *finally* implementing it in Visual Studio 2015, which had a community demo version released on Tuesday; it won't get released until 2015, naturally.